# Include File that is not in the same directory as script

Tags: compilation, include, nsis

I have a NSIS script that is attempting to include a .NSI file that sits in a different folder.

**My Problem:** When I go to compile my script I get the compile error `!include: could not find: "../Utilities.nsi"`. This file exists and is in the correct location I am specifying(in the parent directory - one step back).

How can I include a file that sits in another directory? I hope its possible.

```
!include "../Utilities.nsi" # include error: '!include: could not find: "../Utilities.nsi"'

InstallDir  "abc"
Name        "def"        
OutFile     "def.exe"

Section
    DetailPrint "Hello World"
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Did you read the manual? It says "This command will include 'file' as if it was part of the original script. Note that if a file is included in another directory, the current directory is still where the script was compiled from (not where the included file resides). If the compiler can't find the file it will look for it in every include directory. See !addincludedir for more information. If the /nonfatal switch is used and no files are found, a warning will be issued instead of an error." Also, the examples in the manual do not use quotation marks--did you try removing them? Also, "/" => "\"

Comment: @torazaburo thanks !addincludedir works. You should post as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1):

The [manual](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter5.html#5.1.1) says this about `!include`:

> This command will include 'file' as if it was part of the original
>   script. Note that if a file is included in another directory, the
>   current directory is still where the script was compiled from (not
>   where the included file resides). If the compiler can't find the file
>   it will look for it in every include directory. See !addincludedir for
>   more information. If the /nonfatal switch is used and no files are
>   found, a warning will be issued instead of an error."

Also, the examples in the manual do not use quotation marks -- did you try
removing them? Also, "/" => "\".

Comment: Switching the forward slash for a backslash in !addincludedir helped me. Cheers.